# Laravel Datatables - Export buttons are not showing in table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, datatables

I am running `PHP 7.0.25` and `Laravel Framework 5.5.25`.

I use the [laravel datatables package](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/buttons-installation) and installed/configured the [button plugin](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/buttons-installation).

However, no buttons are shown in my table and I do not get any console error:

[image]

In my composer file I have the following packages:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.0.0",
    "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
    "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
    "yajra/laravel-datatables": "^1.0",
    "yajra/laravel-datatables-buttons": "^3.0",
    "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~8.0"
},
```

My views look like the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

        <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <style>
            body {
                padding-top: 60px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

<body>

    <table class="table table-bordered" id="task-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Created At</th>
                <th>Updated At</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>

<script>
$(function() {
    $('#task-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: '{!! route('datatables.data') !!}',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ],
        columns: [
            { data: 'id', name: 'id' },
            { data: 'name', name: 'name' },
            { data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at' },
            { data: 'updated_at', name: 'updated_at' }
        ]
    });
});
</script>


 <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
        <!-- DataTables -->
        <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
        <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- DataTables Button -->
        <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.1.0/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{URL::asset('js/buttons.server-side.js')}}"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My controller uses the following for the html function:

```
public function html()
{
    return $this->builder()
                ->columns($this->getColumns())
                ->ajax('')
                ->addAction(['width' => '80px'])
                ->parameters([
                    'buttons'      => ['export', 'print', 'reset', 'reload'],
                ]);
}
```

Any suggestions why the buttons do not show up?

I highly appreciate your replies!

Comment: Did you try [these](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/buttons-starter) steps?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define where the button should be rendered. look at the [datatables button docu](https://www.datatables.net/reference/button/). 
The "B" in the [dom parameter](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) is the location of the buttons

```
 ->parameters([
       'dom'          => 'Bfrtip',
       'buttons'      => ['export', 'print', 'reset', 'reload'],
 ]);
```